# Help to understand $\sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} \sum_{1 \leqslant j \lt k} {\frac{1}{k-j}}$

Tags: summation

I got this summation from the book [Concrete Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025) which I didn't exactly understand:

$$
\begin{align}
Sn &= \sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} \sum_{1 \leqslant j \lt k} {\frac{1}{k-j}} \\
&= \sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} \sum_{1 \leqslant k-j \lt k} {\frac{1}{j}} \\
&= \sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} \sum_{0 \lt j \leqslant k-1} {\frac{1}{j}} \\
\end{align} 
$$

I didn't understant why $1 \leqslant j \lt k$ became $1 \leqslant k-j \lt k$ in the second line and why $1 \leqslant k-j \lt k$ became $0 \lt j \leqslant k-1$ in the third line.

Can you guys help me understanding that?

Comment: It seems there is a typo, are you sure of those expressions?

Comment: I am sure they are correct. Just double checked.

Comment: I don't understand the step in teh middle but the final is clear.

Comment: middle step is just writing the limits of j some other way

Comment: @NarendraDeconda Ah yes of course I've oversight the $<$ sign!

Comment: @NarendraDeconda Anyway it should be $$...= \sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} \sum_{1 \leqslant k-j \lt k} {\frac{1}{k-j}}=...$$

Comment: it will be $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{k-j=0}^{k-1} \dfrac{1}{k-j}$. There might be sume connfusion in using j in all the steps. Take $k-j$ as a different variable, say $\alpha$ and proceed further. In the end, replace $\alpha $ with j

Comment: @NarendraDeconda Why are you assuming  $0\le k-j\le k-1$? the sum considered implies $1\le k-j\le k-1$, the same error/typo is still present in your answer.

Comment: @gimusi, everywhere replace k with k-1 in my answers and comments. I hope that makes everything clear. In the question itself, the limits of j should be $1 \leq j \leq k-1$

Comment: How is the sum given in the OP $$Sn = \sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} \sum_{1 \leqslant j \lt k} {\frac{1}{k-j}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\dfrac{1}{k-j}$$ equal to the one you started with $$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\dfrac{1}{k-j}$$

Comment: @gimusi, i have corrected it. thanks

Comment: @NarendraDeconda Well done! Finally you get my point. Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\dfrac{1}{k-j}$$

Let $k-j =\alpha$. Limits of $\alpha$ will be $1 \leq \alpha \leq k-1$, which is same as $1 \leq k-\alpha \leq k-1$.

$$\implies S_n =  \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{k-\alpha=1}^{k-1}\dfrac{1}{\alpha} =\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{\alpha=1}^{k-1}\dfrac{1}{\alpha}= \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\dfrac{1}{j}$$

Comment: The first should be $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\dfrac{1}{k-j}$

Comment: $0 \leq \alpha \leq k-1$ can also be written as $1 \leq k-\alpha \leq k$. I guess the question is correct

Comment: I'm referring to the first line, in the OP $1\le j<k$ that is $1\le j\le k-1$.

Comment: yes. the summation wont exist if j takes the value of k. it should be $1 \leq j \leq k-1$

Answer (score 2):

From here

$$S_n = \sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} \sum_{1 \leqslant j \lt k} {\frac{1}{k-j}}=\ldots $$

since $k-j$ goes from $k-1$ down to  $1$ we have

$$\ldots=\sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} \, \sum_{1 \leqslant k-j \lt k} {\frac{1}{k-j}} =\ldots$$

now we change name to the index using $j$ insted of $k-j$

$$\ldots=\sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} \,\sum_{1 \leqslant j\lt k} {\frac{1}{j}}=\sum_{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n} \,\sum_{0 \lt j\leqslant k-1} {\frac{1}{j}}$$